# Get orders by meta data via WooCommerce WC_Order_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, query-variables

How can I get a WooCommerce order by its number (instead of its ID)?

I tried using wc_get_orders with custom args, like:

```
wc_get_orders( array( 'number' => '1000' ) );
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order numbers functionality is really enabled through a third party plugin in WooCommerce… Then in this case a new `meta_key` exist in `wp_postmeta` database table for `shop_order` WooCommerce post type which is `_order_number`.

So this parameter doesn't exist by default when using `wc_get_orders()` *(in a `WC_Order_Query`)*.

**But you can add/enable the "`number`" parameter** using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_order_number_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_order_number_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['number'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_order_number',
            'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['number'] ),
        );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Now you can use **`number`** parameter to get an order from it's order number via a `WC_Order_Query`:

```
$order = wc_get_orders( array( 'number' => 1000 ) );
```

---

**See in the documentation:** [Adding Custom Parameter Support in a WC_Order_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support).

Comment: Hey there again, unfortunately the meta key of `_order_number` does not seem to exist and therefore, the filtering does not work... I can see other fields, like `_billing_first_name` or `_order_total`, but not `_order_number`. Where else could it be?

Comment: I tried to add code like this: `$test = \wc_get_orders(array('number' => 10));` in my custom WooCoomerce plugin but I'm getting this error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_orders() in /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/src/myfile.php` . Any suggestions?